# Flash AS2 htmlText works in CS3, but not in CS6

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, textfield, flash-cs6, htmltext

I have a problem with an old (Flash CS3) Flash-File in ActionScript 2.

I have a dynamic textfield on the stage containing HTML-text in bold and italic.
Anti-Aliasing is set to "Readability".

If i *trace(myTextField.htmlText)* i get the following output:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="DejaVu Sans" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Hello <FONT FACE="DejaVu Sans Bold"><B>bold </B><FONT FACE="DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique"><B><I>and </I></B><FONT FACE="DejaVu Sans Oblique"><I>italic</I></FONT></FONT></FONT></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

The required fonts "DejaVu Sans", "DejaVu Sans Bold", "DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique" and "DejaVu Sans Oblique" are embedded.

Now i have to change the text inside the textfield with actionscript:

```
 myTextField.htmlText = "This word should appear <b>bold</b> or <i>italic</i>.";
```

In the old CS3-Flash it works as expected.
In the new CS6-Flash the HTML-styles "b" and "i" get ignored.

What is the difference? What have i to do to get it work again?

Testfile:  http://download.reine-schoenheit.de/html_text.zip

Comment: Are you sure that the textbox in the CS6 file has render text as html enabled?

Comment: Yes, i checked it. (And it wouldn't work in CS3, too, if it wasn't enabled.)